# Disable Swipe to New Tab Gesture in Google Chrome Mobile for Android

Tags: android, google-chrome

Google Chrome Mobile for Android navigates to the next or previous tab if a use swipes near the left of right edges of the screen. This is breaking the functionality of my web app which has full-screen swiping to browse images. Is there a way to disable this feature completely or on specific elements?

Comment: I sure hope not. You're asking to break the functionality of the browser in return for "fixing" your web app.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to currently disable the swipe tab gesture

Comment: There's a ticket requesting changes to this feature over at https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=117657

Comment: @JaffaTheCake it is unlikely to be changed.